# Wrap part of string in HTML tags based on position and length

Tags: javascript, html, string

Given this string:

```
var str = 'One two three four five';
```

and this parameters:

```
position: 8
length: 5
```

I would like to wrap the part of the string that starts at the given position and has the given length inside SPAN tags. In this case, I want this result:

```
'One two <span>three</span> four five'
```

How can this be done most elegantly?

---

**Update:** My own solution is here: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/XjbvN/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str = 'One two three four five';
var position = 8
var length = 5

var newstr=str.slice(0,position)+'<span>'+str.slice(position,position+length)+'</span>'+str.slice(position+length);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str.substr(0, position) 
+ "<span>" 
+ str.substr(position, length) 
+ "</span>" 
+ str.substr(position + length, str.length)
```

Not sure if this is what you mean by elegant...

Answer (score 1):

The concept of most elegant is likely subjective.

Most *simply*:

```
var str = 'One two three four five';

var position = 8;
var length = 5;

var newStr = str.substr(0, position) + '<span>' + str.substr(position, length) + '</span>' + str.substr(position + length);
```

Comment: Yea, I guess that's the way to do it... `:)`